# print const char array by the result of sizeof()

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int constChars(const char* str) {
    int size = sizeof(str)/sizeof(char);
    printf("Size is %d.\n", size);
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
       printf("%c ", str[i]);

    return 0;
}


int main(void) {

    char a[10]={'b','c','d','e','f','f','f','f','f','f'};
    constChars(a);
    return 0;

}
```

I wrote piece of code like above, but the output result is:
Size is 8.
b c d e f f f f

I'm quite confused, why the sizeof() function gives a size of 8?
I use gcc and freebsd.

Comment: Pointers are not arrays. You are computing the size of the pointer argument, not of the array object.

Comment: I just changed a little bit, the size is from sizeof(str)/sizeof(char). so its the some problem u r talking about?

Comment: You're measuring the size of str, not of a[]. str is a pointer... make a[] any size you want, and you'll still get 8 every time (4 on a 32-bit system).

Comment: BTW, sizeof(char) is 1 by definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass an array to a function, it gets rewritten as a pointer, where `sizeof` information is lost. If you did this in `main` instead, i.e:

```
char a[10]={'b','c','d','e','f','f','f','f','f','f'};
int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
printf("Size is %d.\n", size);
```

It prints `10` as expected. But once you pass it to `constChars`, it prints the size of a pointer.

Comment: So is it possible to get the size of a const array inside a function by its pointer?

Comment: @robbie88 No, you have to pass the length along with the array.

Comment: It might be worth noting that NULL-terminating character streams is the conventional solution to this problem. By adding a `\0` to the end of the character array, you can iterate through a string until a `\0` is reached. This is how [`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) works.

Answer (score 0):

Str is a pointer to a char. That is typically 4 to 8 bytes. You are not getting the size of the array, but the size of the variable. The only way to know the length of the array is to pass the size in with it, or you could deliminate the array with some sort of signal value (like \0) and do some iteration.